# Error on installing vuejs admin panel with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am installing vue js admin panel with laravel but getting this error i tried a lot to resolve it

[this is error i am facing when run npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtH0V.jpg)

Comment: here look like the module did not find in App.vue , put your component , js file here so that others can understand what is the problem

Comment: Do fresh LARAVEL project download. Step 2- Replace package.json content , with the content from the link provided above. Step 3- Through command prompt - npm install --no-bin-links Step 4- Through command prompt - npm rebuild

Comment: code is too long to post

Comment: Did you configure webpack to resolve alias of the `@` symbol?  Something like this: https://gist.github.com/rppf/bbf28b9442c41ad97a66c3c564df6223#file-webpack-mix-js-L33  It's looking to resolve `@/components/AppDrawer` which should resolve `@` to some base directory.